# Определение РАЗМЕРА (не пикселей) отображаемой страницы

Tags: html5, кроссбраузерность

Делаю страничку под разные устройства впервые. Нужно сделать чтоб если ширина монитора достаточно большая (монитор больше 17 дюймов как комп), то выдаем такую страницу:

```css
#Menu{
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 1px;
  background: #aaffff;
}
#Content{
  width: 65%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 1px 1px 1px 5%;
  background: #ffaaff;
  float: left;
}
#AddContent{
  width: 25%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 1px;
  background: #ffffaa;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
      <div id="Menu">
        Меню
      </div>
      <div id="Content">
        Контент
      </div>
      <div id="AddContent">
        Дополнитеьный блок
      </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Если страница на планшете (больше 8 дюймов), то выдаем такую страницу:

```css
#Menu{
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 1px;
  background: #aaffff;
}
#Content{
  width: 90%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 1px 1px 1px 5%;
  background: #ffaaff;
}
#AddContent{
  width: 90%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 1px 1px 1px 5%;
  background: #ffffaa;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
      <div id="Menu">
        Меню
      </div>
      <div id="Content">
        Контент
      </div>
      <div id="AddContent">
        Дополнитеьный блок
      </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Если страница на смартфоне (меньше 8 дюймов), то выдаем такую страницу:

```css
#Menu{
  width: 20px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 1px 1px 1px 5%;
  background: #aaffff;
  float: left;
}
#Content{
  width: 90%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 1px 1px 1px 5%;
  background: #ffaaff;
}
#AddContent{
  width: 90%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 1px 1px 1px 5%;
  background: #ffffaa;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
      <div id="Menu">
        М.
      </div>
      <div id="Content">
        Контент
      </div>
      <div id="AddContent">
        Дополнитеьный блок
      </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Причем роль играет ширина страницы (если планшет повернуть в альбомную ориентацию, то поведение должно быть как на смартфоне). И нужны не пиксели, потому как смартфоны могут иметь разрешение 1024х768, как и компы.

Какие есть варианты получить такое поведение (шрифт тоже должен подбираться)?

Comment: http://htmlbook.ru/css/value/media

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все так и работает, как вы описали.

1. Можете скачать практически любой *css фраймворк* - в нем уже встроена *сетка (grid system)*, которая адаптируется к ширине экрана. Вот посмотрите, например, [twitter-bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options)
2. Добавляете `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"/>` в `<head>` страницы.
3. Может быть реально смартфон и имеет разрешение 1920х1080, но там есть магия с *device pixel ratio*. С помощью этого значения происходит пересчет разрешения. Прочитайте, например, [эту статью](https://habrahabr.ru/post/159419/) и [этот вопрос на enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8785643/what-exactly-is-device-pixel-ratio).
4. Шрифты браузер масштабирует автоматически
5. *Медиа запросы (media queries)* в css. На них построены сетки, встроенные в фреймворки. Разработчики просто выбрали граничные условия и не привязываются к конкретному типу устройства (вам в конце концов никто не запрещает уменьшить окно браузера на ПК).

Все это называется *адаптивный дизайн / резиновая разметка / адаптивная верстка*.

В Chrome в инструментах разработчика есть полезная кнопочка (слева сверху) с изображением мобильного телефона. Она позволяет проверять резиновость разметки и имеет предустановки для нескольких телефонов/планшетов.

Предположим, что у меня есть twitter bootstrap, тогда пример стилей для вашего меню выглядел бы примерно так:

```
// УСЛОВНО на смартфоне (портрет)
#Menu {
  width: 20px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 1px 1px 1px 5%;
  background: #aaffff;
  float: left;
}

// УСЛОВНО на планшете (портрет)
@media(min-width: 768px) {
  #Menu {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 1px;
    background: #aaffff;
  }
}

// УСЛОВНО на мониторе 19 дюймов
@media(min-width: 992px) {
  #Menu {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 1px;
    background: #aaffff;
  }
}
```

Также, существует подход, называемый *mobile-first*. Это значит что стили сначала создаются для малого размера экрана (условно мобильного телефона), а потом media запросами добавляются стили для бОльших размеров экрана (для планшета, потом для ПК). Вы можете делать наоборот.

Answer (score 2):

вы наверно не понимаете что-то...дюймы те же пиксели только в другой системе исчисления...можна для различных экранов использовать медиа-запросы. И советую посмотреть в сторону Viewport

Comment: То есть document.documentElement.clientWidth будет выдавать реальные размеры экрана (только переведенные в определенные единицы измерения)?

Comment: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" /> это на тему вьюпортов... а вообще пишут под размер окна браузера..возможно пользователь не хочет браузер на весь экран..а скажем на половину экрана(тогда у вас полосы прокруток будут)..лучше к реальному размеру не привязывать. в медиа-запросы сами определяют какие стили подгрузить к  определенной ширине экрана.

Comment: хотя чисто для технического отображения информации вот статья http://shublog.ru/ajax/jquery/kak-opredelit-razreshenie-ekrana-i-razmer-okna-brauzera/ тут показано как на js узнать реальные размеры..но сомнительно как по мне для такого нагружать js..простого html/css хватает

Answer (score 0):

Примените запросы **@media** для ваших стилей. Я применяю только один (как мне кажется универсальный) запрос **@media screen and (max-width:45em)**. **[Инфо W3](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)** ++ **[Инфо2 W3](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)** ++ **[Инфо Moz](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)**